# How to create a dbf file and insert a list to it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a DBF File using python and insert a list into it, Can anybody help any suggestions this is the code I have.

```
             db = dbf.Dbf("test.dbf", new=True)
             for row in table:
                db.append(rows)
```

I get this error:

```
      File "C:\Python37-32\pr_import.py", line 350, in proceed
      db = dbf.Dbf("test.dbf", new=True)
      NameError: name 'dbf' is not defined
```

Comment: How are you defining or importing dbf. like the error says, your trying to use a name thats not defined

Comment: from dbfread import DBF, I use that to open my dbf file and read it

Comment: python is case sensitive. in your case, `DBF` is defined, but `dbf` is not

Comment: I get this error now        '  File "C:\Python37-32\pr_import.py", line 350, in proceed
                                      db = DBF.Dbf("test.dbf", new=True)
                                       AttributeError: type object 'DBF' has no attribute 'Dbf'  '

Comment: Any help? more suggestions

Comment: the error is pretty Clear, DBF doesnt have an attribute/method/class called `Dbf` look at the documentation or source code

Comment: is there another way?